# Extracting specific rows from each text files and store in one txt file

Tags: r, extract, rows

```
   ListOfFileNames= list.files(path = "D:/in/",
                       pattern = '*.txt',recursive = T)
   options(stringsAsFactors = F)
   setwd("D:/in/")
   outFile <- file("output.txt", "w")
   for (i in ListOfFileNames){
     x = read.delim(ListOfFileNames[i], skip = 29, nrows= 1)
     x = as.character(x)
    writeLines(x, paste('D:/out/out.csv',sep = ","))

   }
```

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gO-ifIzTjx6dt2cw12jOmkSY7sqLK-3Y?usp=sharing)[This the txt files that I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1buBw.png)

I would like to extract row number 30 and 63 from each txt file and save it into one txt file. How can I solve this in R ?  This is the codes that I try to extract row number 30 and store it in one csv file. But it doesn't work. Could you please help ?

Thanks

Comment: Share two files and show us the code you have tried so far. If its confidential then change it according to your need otherwise no way anyone here can help you.

Comment: okay I will upload two files.

Comment: You need this right "C2,2020-03-13,10:00:00,136.99" and "C2,2020-03-14,19:00:00,133.14". File name 03_19_C2.txt

Comment: yes correct. same number of rows from another txt files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
ListOfFileNames= list.files(path = "D:/in/",
                       pattern = '*.txt',recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ListOfFileNames, function(x) 
                  read.csv(x)[c(30, 63), ]))

write.csv(result, 'D:/out/out.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank y0u but it gives me many files. I want to get only one file.

Comment: @KayKhaingKyaw See updated answer to get only one combined file at the end.